# Kafka Broker Version Question and enable.idempotence

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

Probably a noob question:

I have started a Bitnami Kafka Container from bitnami/kafka:2
In startup messages it claims to be Version 2.5
Now i wanted to use enable.idempotence but when i try this with librdkafka 1.4.0, i get an error message saying:

```
Required feature not supported by broker: Idempotent producer not supported by any of the 1 connected broker(s): requires Apache Kafka broker version >= 0.11.0
```

From my naive pov, 2.5 appears to be >=0.11.0 ... but probably i am missing something.
Can anybody help?

Comment: with the 2.5 version you are probably referring to the kafka-clients, not the broker version.

Comment: librdkafka version is 1.4.0. But Kafka service says during startup: 
[2020-05-06 19:10:59,986] INFO Kafka version: 2.5.0 ... also: `kafka-topics.sh --version` ---> reports ---->
2.5.0 (Commit:66563e712b0b9f84)

Comment: Have you tried the confluent containers?

Comment: no, but bitnami is known for updating their containers frequently. and the confluent containers seem quite complicated and bloated with functionality i do not need.

Comment: Please post your producer configs.